# Send message from Text

Tags: javascript

I am getting `Error: Please make sure that the message parameter is a string!`.
How do I return an array of text from my text file and auto-send that from the loop?

```
    // read contents of the file
    const data = fs.readFileSync('mr_robot.txt', 'UTF-8');
    const lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
    let n_lines = 1;
    for (let l_indx = 0; l_indx < lines.length; l_indx++) {
        var message = lines
    }
    autosend.PostLoop(message, channelID, tokenID, minimum, maximum)
```

Example text from .txt

```
Hey! Hey! Hey! Boy's not picking up.
Okay, okay, okay.
I got you, man.
I didn't know that.
All right, I got you.
All right.
Yeah, you got me confused.
```

Comment: What error? Also, before we continue, would you mind either posting the image as text without the racial slur or censor it?

Comment: I am trying to automate a send message line by line from a text file. Somehow I am getting an error that my parameter is not a string

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? In `PostLoop` you want to return an array of all the lines in the file?

Comment: when I just pass in var message = "Some text here" instead of a for loop
It returns successfully and able to send the message

Comment: @GaryHoliday yes, in postloop it should be able to grab line1 and post the message
Then grabs line2 sends the message and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are assigning message to your original array `lines`. You are looping but not indexing anything.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but if you want to call `PostLoop` per message you need to do something like this:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('mr_robot.txt', 'UTF-8');
const lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
let n_lines = 1;
for (let l_indx = 0; l_indx < lines.length; l_indx++) {

    var message = lines[l_indx];
    autosend.PostLoop(message, channelID, tokenID, minimum, maximum);
}
```